# trigger.('click') works only once?

Tags: jquery

I have article. And user sends new comment. I have code

```
if (c.length === 0) { 
  el.trigger('click');
} else { 
  el.trigger('click'); 
  el.trigger('click'); 
}
```

If it doesnt exist block with comments then it trigger click and comments appear using ajax. But if it exist block with comments then it needs to trigger click twice to remove block with comments and to show block with new comments. I have problem because trigger click works only once. How to make to trigger twice?

Comment: You can use `el.dblclick();` function.

Comment: The problem is most likely because you're triggering the events too quickly. Try using a timeout on the second one. Or - even better - stop faking events, and actually call the function which contains the logic you want to run directly

Comment: @Nail Malek, dblclick() not working

Comment: timeout for the second click should do the trick

Comment: So as of Rory McCrossan you can use setTimeout function to second click triger. @Laravelchik

Comment: what is the code in click event handler? try putting simple alert to test.

Comment: @PrashantShirke an alert would put in a fake time delay so that the second click would run later and not be seen as a double click (so should work with the alert and then stop working when you remove the alert)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, settimeout works) It really triggering the events too quickly. Maybe its bad practice, I think about logic.